# How to disable drop-list / hint LOGCAT in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently move from Android Studio to Intellij, but IntelliJ has a function that make me annoying everytime, the dialog showed and prevents me to paste from clipboard, so I lost a little bit of time to press ESC key, and then paste again. Does anyone have this kind of experience, please give advice!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMt8t.png)

Comment: Lack of details. Do you see that popup every time you try to paste anything? What is the name of the dialog that opens? Do you have custom plugins installed?

Comment: Konstantin, this popup show every time I click to the text field. (I've just fresher using IntelliJ recently, not install anything)